# Game slows a little bit when I'm moving

Tags: java, performance, buffering

I have a little problem with buffering objects in Java. I have this piece of code (I'm trying to make a simple platform game):

```
public void timeLoop() {
    Timer t = new Timer();
    TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            p.update(boxhandler.getObj());
            repaint();
        }
    };

    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(tt, 0l, 17l);
}
```

And the problem is game have little lags/scratches/backflows whatever it is called. That's not very big latency, but I now I will be getting this more while improve my code.

So, what's in my code I have showed? I have a loop with `TimerTask` which is updating all objects saved in `BoxHandler` class (it simply register all tiles and record in list) and next I'm calling repaint all class (it extends `JLabel`).

I want to add that game is slowing a little bit after every second - objects are slowing for very short time and return to their proper position.

How can I improve my code? I can't do it simpler. I have about 50 tiles in my game and it slows when I'm moving a game character.

I gave this code because I think it is reason of my problems.

Comment: Do you call `timeLoop()` more than once?

Comment: No, only one time, in constructor which is called later in main method.

Comment: Try narrowing down the source of your problem methodically. For example, comment out as much of the game logic as possible, then test. Re-enable logic until the problem manifests. Take a look at that logic. Some *minor* frame stutter is to be expected naturally though, if you're working with Swing (e.g. a repaint being late by a few milliseconds every now and then).